# Python - Pandas - Extract ENTIRE excel file as string

Tags: python, pandas, converters

I'd like to read a lot of excel files using pandas (python). When importing the data, I want ALL my columns to be stored as strings.

The problem is that I don't know the number of columns or even their names (it changes every time). Would you have an easy solution for this problem?

What I tried to do:

```
converters = { i : str for i in range(0,99)}
df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx', converters = converters)
```

But the Index gets out of range sometimes since the excel files are different.

Ideally I'd like to do:

```
df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx', converters = ALL)
```

Nevertheless, I haven't found something that would help me doing something similar so far...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx').asytpe(str)` ?

Comment: MaxU, I don't think DataFrame objects have asytpe attribute

Comment: can you share the error from using `converters = { i : str for i in range(0,99)}`

Comment: piRSquared, "Index is out of Range". Which makes sense since the excel file is different every time. Sometimes a file has 99 columns, sometimes it has 10 columns. If the dictionary has more element than columns the index will be out of range.

Comment: @user7410504 yeah, I just replicated that... thinking...

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:** i think we can use the standard (for Pandas) `xlrd` module and then reuse for reading data from the Excel file

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(fn)
ncols = xl.book.sheet_by_index(0).ncols
df = xl.parse(0, converters={i : str for i in range(ncols)})
```

**OLD answer:**

I think you would have first to get number of columns:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook = load_workbook(filename, use_iterators=True)
col_num = workbook.worksheets[0].max_column

converters = { i : str for i in range(col_num)}
...
```

Comment: When I try to upvote again... it just takes it way.  Which isn't what I want.  How do I upvote twice?  This is my next meta question.

Comment: Thanks MaxU: it works for most cases but sometimes I have extra columns at the end of the file that are not part of the table I extract (I used skiprow to avoid them). So in your code `col_num` would be too high and the index would be out of range.
A solution I found would be to use `read_excel` two times: the first time to get `df.columns.max` (after skipping the rows I don't need) and then the second time using `converters  = { i : str for i in range(df.columns.max)}`.
Nevertheless I would like to avoid reading the excel files two times....

Comment: @user7410504 if you want to avoid reading it multiple times, it really should be in a better format.  This is the reason we use formats, so we can avoid doing inefficient things.

Comment: Yeah I agree. It's just that I'm dealing with a lot of heavy files (that I didn't create myself). Reformatting is a pain :)